# Actively remove user from chat channel in Elixir

Tags: elixir, chat, erlang-otp

I'm a beginner in Elixir and I'm working on a simple chat server with multiple channels.

My channel is a `GenServer`, and it stores a list of users (pids), and also a map (user ref -> pid) to deal with user process crashes (From [Elixir Guides](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html#the-need-for-monitoring)). But since it's a map with refs as keys, when I implemented the `remove_member_from_channel` function, that I wanted to remove the pid (the value of the map), how can I do it? Or did I choose the wrong way to implement it?

```
defmodule Chat.Channel do
  use GenServer

  # ......

  def add_member(channel, user) do
    GenServer.call(channel, {:add_member, user})
  end

  def remove_member(channel, user) do
    GenServer.call(channel, {:remove_member, user})
  end

  # ......

  def handle_call({:add_member, user}, _from, {members, refs}) do
    if Enum.member?(members, user) do
      {:reply, :already_added, {members, refs}}
    else
      new_members = [user | members]
      ref = Process.monitor(user)
      new_refs = Map.put(refs, ref, user)
      {:reply, :ok, {new_members, new_refs}}
    end
  end

  def handle_call({:remove_member, member}, _from, {members, refs}) do
    if Enum.member?(members, member) do
      new_members = List.delete(members, member)

      # What to do with refs??

      {:reply, :ok, {new_members, refs}}
    else
      {:reply, :member_not_added, {members, refs}}
    end
  end

  def handle_info({:DOWN, ref, :process, _pid, _reason}, {members, refs}) do
    {member, new_refs} = Map.pop(refs, ref)
    new_members = List.delete(members, member)
    {:noreply, {new_members, new_refs}}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) (or [`Enum.reject/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2):

```rb
def handle_call({:remove_member, member}, _from, {members, refs}) do
  if Enum.member?(members, member) do
    new_members = List.delete(members, member)
    new_refs =
      Enum.filter(refs, fn
        {_ref, ^member} -> false
        _ -> true
      end)
    {:reply, :ok, {new_members, refs}}
  else
    {:reply, :member_not_added, {members, refs}}
  end
end
```

In general, I’d better store the `used_id ⇒ reference` map, something like:

```rb
new_refs = Map.put(refs, user, ref) # or even better used.id
```

that way one might simply use [`Map.delete/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#delete/2) later:

```rb
...
  new_members = List.delete(members, member)
  new_refs = Map.delete(refs, member) # or member.id
```

Comment: Is it means that, if we store it as `user_pid = reference`, when a user process crashes, we have to use `Enum.filter/2` or `Enum.reject/2` to remove it? Since we can only get the reference when it crashes.

Comment: Uhoh, indeed, true that. Well, one might maintain _both_ `user ⇒ ref` and `ref ⇒ user` maps then.